# Angular 4 failed to load scss after adding a component

Tags: angular

I got an error like this in my Angular 4 web app.

[image: Error message]

It was happened after I generated a `upload-button` component using cli, copy-&-pasted some code from other component's html & scss file to `upload-button.component.html` and `upload-button.component.scss` and the error suddenly appears in my browser console with all my app blank with just plain white screen. I didn't even touch any of `.ts` file since then.

The error says the app cannot load my newly made component's scss, but when I look up into Sources panel, the component is loaded into the browser completely.

[image]

I have already deleted the component, even created a new project and copied all of `src/app` content into the same path on new project, but the message still appears.

Here is my Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.2
Node: 7.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

p.s. I didn't change any of Webpack configuration or else.

Please advise.

Comment: What's the error in your terminal?

Comment: `ng serve` did not show any error

Comment: Your screenshot shows 4 console errors, but you've only provided one in your question. What are the other console errors?

Comment: it was just a missing ionicons.css, and the other one is little error in my custom js file for handling input text behavior. they are not a big deal as the app can still run with those error.

Answer (score 1):

After rechecked all the component, I found a misplaced `<link href="...">` in one of the component. I'm not sure how it was there but I'm glad that the app working back again.

Answer (score 0):

check if your StyleUrls is loading correctly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: it is correct as I didn't modify any of the angular cli outcome